# C# app with WebBrowser (WinForms) control causes vshost to crash after a while

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

Below is my code, and what happens when I run this code, first of all it runs for about an hour freely (eating a lot memory - starts from around 400MB RAM and goes up to 1GB), but after an hour or so VSHOST crashes and Visual Studio doesn't catch any exception.. 
Any ideas why this is happening? 
tnx :)

```
    private void UpdateLastPosted()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string html = wc.DownloadString("http://blogs.com/lastblogs.aspx");
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(html, @"blogs\.com/blogread\.asp\?blog=(\d+)");
        foreach (Match pend in collection)
        {
            pending.Enqueue(pend.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }

    private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((WebBrowser)sender).ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            if (pending.Count > 0)
            {
                ((WebBrowser)sender).Stop();
                NavigateTo("http://blogs.com/blogread.asp?blog=" + pending.Dequeue());
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateLastPosted();
                UpdateMostActive();
                if (pending.Count > 0)
                {
                    ((WebBrowser)sender).Stop();
                    NavigateTo("http://blogs.com/blogread.asp?blog=" + pending.Dequeue());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string url)
    {
        browser.Navigate(url);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For every element in the html page the method browser_DocumentCompleted is called. Try specifiying the exact or similar url :

```
private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Url.OriginalString.ToLower() == "http://www.myisite.com/contact.aspx")
        {
           ......
```